# Custom unique identifier in mongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

On the process of creating a MERN stack app for a school, and I encountered a unique requirement where I was tasked to create a really custom ID for a specific collection, the requirement goes like this.

first of, this is a sample identifier that will be generated.

"01012023G601"

1. `01012023` part is the date today which is pretty trivial to do.
2. `G6` part is the student level, in this example `Grade 6` -- student levels is stored on another collection ranging from `grade 1 - grade 10`.
3. `01` this last part is where I'm having trouble which is an incrementing value.

Imagine if you are encoding a lot of students within the day and 5 of those student are of the same grade `g6`

those student should be stored on the collection with the unique identifier - from `01012023G601` up to `01012023G605`

My problem is that there are thousands of student encoders all around the globe so how can I ensure that the unique identifier created pre-save is actually unique.

in my pre-save I have this generator that creates the identifier.

```
const today = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');
const prefix = <get correct grade level and append it to today>
const highestExisting = await this.constructor.findOne({ uniqueIdentifier: new RegExp(`^${prefix}`) })
        .sort({ uniqueIdentifier: -1 })
        .select('uniqueIdentifier')
        .lean();

<increment the last digit from the query by 1 and save>
```

is there a more trivial way to do this or a step to optimize?

Comment: Create a unique index on the field, that's their purpose